# Downscale image through URL

Tags: image, url, resize

Let's say I'd like to make the height of this image 800px: http://blog.press.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/YdvkXNmW.jpeg

Is there a website that can automatically set the height at 800px while keeping the same ratio through only a URL?

I want it to work through just a URL like this:

```
downscaled.com/800px/blog.press.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/YdvkXNmW.jpeg
```

Like I just have to put the URL in and get a downscaled version

Comment: "please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response" Did you check the inner exception? That will likely contain more details on the cause.

Comment: Write the entire exception to your logcat, and you'll be able to get the message and stack trace from all nested exceptions there.

Comment: I think we've gotten questions with a similar error message regularly here. I don't recall what the solution was, but searching for that error message should get you some more directly usable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL looks slightly different, but quick search gave me cloudimg.io service that does what you described:

```
https://demo.cloudimg.io/height/800/n/http://blog.press.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/YdvkXNmW.jpeg
```

To avoid upscaling, one can use [foil1 filter](https://docs.cloudimage.io/go/cloudimage-documentation/en/operations/width-height).

```
https://demo.cloudimg.io/height/800/foil1/http://www.olgakuts.com/ip_themes/lt_pagan/img/header.jpg
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is it possible to only resize when the image's height is more than 800?

Comment: For example, I don't want an image with a height of 400px to be upscaled to 800.

Comment: Yes. How is it possible to only resize when the image's height is more than 800?

Comment: You should use foil1 filter as described in documentation